# 子要素の子要素がXXでない CSSセレクタ

Tags: css

`nav ul li:not(a > img)`というコードを書いていましたが、notは結合子が使えないようなので、書き直しています。
だれか、できませんか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

現状では、CSSのセレクタ−に子要素を条件とするものがないのでCSSだけで書くことは不可能です。

なお、Selectors Level 4 の草案には[`:has()`擬似クラス](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/:has)があるので、将来的にはできるようになるかもしれません。

また、`jQuery`を使うと以下のようにして、子要素の子要素がXXである要素を取得できるので、JavaScriptを使って表示させるようにするか、Node.jsを使って、HTMLファイルを修正して、要素にクラス名の設定すればいいでしょう。

```
jQuery("nav ul li > a > img").parent().parent()
```